# Hive not showing data from HBase table

Tags: hive, hbase

I have created the below HBase table and inserted one record.

```
hbase(main):001:0> create 'table3', 'col_fam1', 'col_fam2', 'col_fam3'
0 row(s) in 1.8280 seconds

hbase(main):008:0> put 'table3', 'row1', 'col_fam1:c11', 'val11'
0 row(s) in 0.0980 seconds

hbase(main):009:0> put 'table3', 'row1', 'col_fam1:c12', 'val12'
0 row(s) in 0.0060 seconds

hbase(main):010:0> put 'table3', 'row1', 'col_fam2:c21', 'val21'
0 row(s) in 0.0070 seconds

hbase(main):011:0> put 'table3', 'row1', 'col_fam3:c31', 'val31'
0 row(s) in 0.0090 seconds
```

When I am trying to see the data from HBase table it is showing correctly.

```
hbase(main):029:0> scan 'table3'
ROW                                  COLUMN+CELL                                                                                               
 row1                                column=col_fam1:c11, timestamp=1430986499437, value=val11                                                 
 row1                                column=col_fam1:c12, timestamp=1430986509448, value=val12                                                 
 row1                                column=col_fam2:c21, timestamp=1430986519155, value=val21                                                 
 row1                                column=col_fam3:c31, timestamp=1430986527751, value=val31                                                 
1 row(s) in 0.0390 seconds
```

Next I have created a HIVE table

```
hive> create external table hive_hbase_table3 (
    key string, 
    col11 string, 
    col12 string, 
    col21 string, 
    col31 string
    ) 
    stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
    with serdeproperties (
      "hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,col_fam1:col11, col_fam1:col12, col_fam2:col21, col_fam3:col31"
    ) tblproperties(
      "hbase.table.name" = "table3"
    );
OK
Time taken: 0.996 seconds
```

But when I am selecting from the HIVE table no row found. Ideally one row should be selected.

```
hive> select * from hive_hbase_table3;
OK
Time taken: 0.718 seconds
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did this work for anyone? I am still unable to find out the issue in it.

Comment: Sorry it was very bad typo from my end. In the column mapping section I have mentioned Col11, Col12, Col21, Col31 but instead it will be C11, C12, C21,C31.

Comment: The correct query :-                                                                                              CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hivehbase_tbl3 
(col1 string, col2 string, col3 string, col4 string, col5 string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES       
("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,col_fam1:c11,col_fam1:c12,col_fam2:c21,col_fam3:c31") 
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "table3");

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: This has worked for me after changing the versions. HIVE with 1.1.0 and HBASE 0.98